# search engine for javascript or / and css by source code snippets

Tags: javascript, search-engine

this is not a programming question as such but still...

does anyone know of a service / spider / crawler that can fetch javascript or CSS resources embedded through standard methods (or lazy loading, whatever it can cope with)

practical use for it: search for a unique piece of code from a class or function you've written and get a list of sites that reference it. or, for that matter, search for something unique out of framework and get an idea of its popularity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.dreamincode.net/code/browse.php?cid=11

and

http://www.dreamincode.net/code/browse.php

Its providing free....

http://www.astahost.com/info.php/free-code-snippets-css-layout_t13198.html

Answer (score 1):

http://www.koders.com/ and http://www.google.com/codesearch ?

Comment: these are cool but limited in that they only display results from a particular set of known projects. 

I would like a search engine that can produce SERPs inclusive of text from javascript files.

Comment: Ah right, I follow you. Okay, I don't know of one that does that. I mean google can kind of do it via `ext:js [term]` but it doesn't seem to have a large index.

Comment: yeah cheers... i am trying to trace sites that have copied js from my site blindly, including my google analytics code, which has created a mess of my stats...